# no axis appear or basic details using .plot() the figure doesn't show axis or details it show just that drawing

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

i dont know why no axis appear or basic details when i write below code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
ted = pd.read_csv('ted.csv')
ted.comments.plot()
plt.figure(figsize=((10,8)))
```

the figure doesn't show axis or details it show just that drawing when i searched i think now one faced this problem

[image]

if the data set for example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

A   B   C   D
```

0   35  21  24  80
1   29  68  94  47
2   89  27  23  70
3   58  67  57  77
4   87  13  59  82
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
95  11  30  44  16
96  14  27  25  68
97  43  59  56  34
98  4   97  53  80
99  64  92  80  6

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.B.plot()
```

i think the problem is not related to the data set as i always get fig without x and y axis

[image]

Comment: can you provide the dataset, or a better a minimum dataset that reproduces the problem?

Comment: i think the problem is not related to the data set as i always get fig without x and y axis for any data

Comment: This is a problem with your default setting, not with the code itself. You have x and y axis, it's just almost invisible because of black background, and your ``fig`` is transparent. set the alpha to 1 and you will see your axis on a white background

Comment: i did what you said but it didn't appear the figure is by default  alpha(1)

Answer (score 0):

Because I use dark theme in Jupyter note book I had to change plt style

```
plt.style.use('dark_background')
```

[image]

Axis appeared.